# How can I write in javascript a text in 2 colors? Every second letter to be red?

Tags: javascript

This is what I got so far but I`m stuck.

```
var s=`First JavaScript string.`; 
var c=`This is second text.`;
var sc = s.concat(c);
var sp=sc.split("");
var colors=[`red`,`black`">; 

for(i=0;i<sc.length;i++) { 
    var span=`<span style="color:`+colors[i % 2">+`;">`+sp+`</span>`;

    document.write(span);
}
```

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with your keyboard. The javascript text delimiter is a quotation not a back-tick. also every time you had `>"` instead of `]`. Also you're creating `i` as a global variable here. (Actually, depending on where you put this, all variables might be global as they are not in a function).

Comment: Also, can you please edit and give some background on what it is that you are trying to do. At the moment it kind of sounds like you're trying to get us to do some homework for you.

Comment: A few things: don't use document.write (at all), and don't write into the DOM in a loop - collect the HTML in a variable and write it all at once (to the parent element's innerHTML property, for example). DOM operations are **costly**.

Comment: @Mörre It's generally not wise to edit a question's code other than formatting. It's very possible the backticks are in OP's actual code as well.

Comment: My bad, I assumed that this was an international keyboard misbehaving as the code posted is so obviously not valid javascript.

Comment: @Mörre this is not appropriate behavior.

Comment: @Juhana Quick question. ` and ' , do these look the same in your screen/browser? Because it's really obvious. At the 4th edit you changed " and ' to `. Probably unintentionally. [Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/if812p31x/)

Comment: @akinuri *sigh* Look at the [OP's original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/d22b8ae7-0904-483c-855d-b3c029e7b467/view-source). The OP had the backticks in the question originally, and George fixed them to quotes. I rolled back to the **original version**. The point is that OP's code should not be fixed by editing it in the question. If you want to tell them that they shouldn't use backticks, write an answer.

Comment: @Juhana Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20385809/1) the original post?

Comment: @akinuri Yes it is. What I linked to is the source. The backticks are there, but the markdown interprets them as signifying code blocks.

Comment: @Juhana Ah, lol. I missed that. Ok, It's [George Mauer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5056/george-mauer)'s fault. Back to him xD

Answer (score 0):

Don't split the string, just use sc[i] instead of sp in last line.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the text with your sp variable. What you want is the current character. In your loop you loop over every character. In this for loop the i is the index. Your sc string is actually an array of characters. Therefore sc[i] points to the current character.

If you change sp to sc[i] your code works correct.

```
var s = "First JavaScript string."; 
var c = "This is second text.";
var sc = s.concat(c);
var colors = ['red','black']; 

for (i=0; i<sc.length; i++) { 
    var span = '<span style="color:' + colors[i % 2] + ';">' + sc[i] + '</span>';
    document.write(span);
}
```

However a more efficient way would be:

```
    var s = "First JavaScript string."; 
    var c = "This is second text.";
    var sc = s.concat(c);
    var colors = ['red','black'];
    var html = "";

    for (i=0; i<sc.length; i++) { 
        html += '<span style="color:' + colors[i % 2] + ';">' +sc[i]+ '</span>';
    }

    document.write(html);
```

Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/4Np9u/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
  var s = "First JavaScript string."; 
    var c = "This is second text.";
    var sc = s.concat(c);
    var colors = ['red','black']; 

    for (i=0; i<sc.length; i++) { 
        var span = '<span style="color:' + colors[i % 2] + ';">' +sc[i]+ '</span>';
        document.write(span);
    }
```

JsFiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/A24q2/

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.

Comment: No problem result is the same, we are trying to help him.

Comment: @AhmetCanGüven: actually *explaining* the errors would have been more helpful. Now the OP can mentally shut down, copy your code and paste it where needed. No further thinking required, job done, all's well.